# How to develop a command like "Show Process" in MySQL using UDF

Tags: mysql, user-defined-functions

In MySQL, I want to develop a custom command which like the following mysql commands which process meta data such as information_schema or performance_schema or user schema :

> **show processlist** or **show variables**

But the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/adding-functions.html) is not enough clear to me to develop a custom function like above said. Any valuable guidance is appreciable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer the following links which provides you good example to create user-defined functions using C.

- http://www.fromdual.com/using-mysql-user-defined-functions-udf
- http://blog.loftdigital.com/blog/how-to-write-mysql-functions-in-c

I think this might help you. If you have any further doubt pls feel free to ask.